# How to POST user to a page from a NodeJS server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http

What I am trying to do seems very simple but I can't figure it out. Right now I am rendering a simple

`<form action="{POST URL}"><button type="submit"></buttton></form>`

Where the user then clicks the submit button which POSTs them to another websites page. What I want it to do though is POST the user there from my NodeJS server here:

```
app.get('/auth', function (req, res) {
apiClient.generateAccessToken(integratorKey, clientSecret, req.query.code, function (err, oAuthToken) {

    console.log("************ACCESS TOKEN**************")
    console.log(oAuthToken.accessToken);
    accessToken = oAuthToken.accessToken;

    apiClient.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);

    // res.post(req.url);
    res.send(`<html lang="en"><body><form action="${req.url}" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign the document!"
        style="width:13em;height:2em;background:blue;color:white;font:bold 1.5em arial;margin: 20px auto; display: block;"/>
        </form></body>`)
});
```

})

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript to submit the form: `document.getElementById('frm').submit()`

Demo:

```
res.send(`<html lang="en"><body><form id="frm" action="${req.url}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign the document!"
    style="width:13em;height:2em;background:blue;color:white;font:bold 1.5em arial;margin: 20px auto; display: block;"/>
    </form><script>document.getElementById('frm').submit()</script></body>`)
```

However, you can not pass other headers (eg: `Authorization`) by the form's POST. If you want to control everything, you should use your own HTTP client to post the request instead of the user's browser.